# How to overlay correctly in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click each cells, `layer counts` of `following 20 cells` will increase.

But my desired result is to decrease `layer counts` when I `red` class is removed.

At this time, it always increases and I couldn't come up with how to decrease `layer counts` in the following 20 cells.

It doesn't matter how to write if we can achieve it.

Is there any sophisticated way to achieve this?

```js
const layerArray=["layer1","layer2","layer3","layer4"];

var ArrLen=layerArray.length;     


$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('red');
    
    index=$("td").index(this);
    
      $("td").slice(index+1,index+20).each(function() {
     
     var classIndex = $(this).data('layer');
     
     classIndex++;
     
     if(classIndex < (ArrLen-1)) {
          
     $(this).addClass(layerArray[classIndex-1]);

     }  else {

    $(this).addClass(layerArray[ArrLen-1]);
     }
        
    $(this).data('layer',classIndex);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
    border: solid black 1px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

div{
  padding: 5px;

}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red{
  background-color:red;}
  
  
.layer1{
    background-color: hsl(60, 90%, 90%);}    

.layer2{
    background-color: hsl(40, 90%, 90%);}    
    
.layer3{
    background-color: hsl(20, 90%, 90%);}    

.layer4{
    background-color: hsl(0, 90%, 90%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>


<script>
Html =' '
Html += '<table>';
let i =0;
for (let w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
    Html += '<tr>';
    for(let d=0; d<10;d++){
           i=i+1;
           Html += '<td data-layer=0>'+'<div>'+i+'</div>'+'</td>'
    }   
    Html += '</tr>';
}
Html +='</table>'

document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = Html;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make use of the `data-layer` you have given to each table cell. We know that you can only click one table cell at a time. We also know that we are adding the layers sequentially (1, then 2, then 3, and finally 4).

We can check if the clicked table cell still has the red class. If it does, adjust the value so that the next 20 table cells' `data-layer` attributes will be incremented by 1. If it doesn't, decrement by 1. As the layers are added sequentially, we can also remove each layer based on the `data-layer` value. If it is 4 and then decreased by 1, we know that we need to remove `layer4`. If it is 3 and then decreased by 1, we know that we need to remove `layer3`. The same logic applies for `layer1` and `layer2` removal.

*Although not necessary, you should probably use the camelcase as it is pretty much the accepted practice for writing variables in JS*.

```js
const layerArray = ["layer1", "layer2", "layer3", "layer4"];

var arrLen = layerArray.length;


$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('red');
    let index = $("td").index(this);
    let layerChange = $(this).children().hasClass('red') ? 1 : -1;
    
    $("td").slice(index + 1, index + 20).each(function() {
      let classIndex = $(this).data('layer');
      classIndex += layerChange;

      if (layerChange === 1 && classIndex - 1 < arrLen) {
        $(this).addClass(layerArray[classIndex - 1])
      } else if (layerChange === -1 && classIndex >= 0) {
        $(this).removeClass(layerArray[classIndex])
      }

      $(this).data('layer', classIndex);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.layer1 {
  background-color: hsl(60, 90%, 90%);
}

.layer2 {
  background-color: hsl(40, 90%, 90%);
}

.layer3 {
  background-color: hsl(20, 90%, 90%);
}

.layer4 {
  background-color: hsl(0, 90%, 90%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>


<script>
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  for (let w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
      i = i + 1;
      html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>'
  document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```